# NSFetchedResultsController sections with duplicate items

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I'm using an NSFetchedResultsController to display data out of my core data database. My model consists of Users and groups

```
`Users <<----->> Groups`
```

A user can have multiple groups and groups can also have multiple users.
I want to display one section for each group, with rows containing users in that group. If a user is in multiple groups he will appear in all sections for groups he is a member of.
I can do this by storing the user object multiple times, once for each group the user is in. But that doesn't work for me as it would break some other use cases, where users must be unique in the database.

Answer (score 0):

A fetch request always returns a list of matching objects, without duplicates.
What you can do is to replace the many-to-many relationship by two one-to-many
relationships with an intermediate Entity:

```
User <-->> UserGroup <<--> Group
```

Then you can fetch all `UserGroup` objects grouped/sectioned by the `group` property, and
display its `user` property in the table view cell.